# Mobx/React Native: State does not update when action is made

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, mobx, mobx-react

I am currently working on creating a sample application using Mobx 6.9.0 and React Native/Expo.
This is my current setup:

App.tsx

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from "mobx-react";
import State from "./src/state";
import Sample from './src/sample/components/Sample';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={State}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Sample/>
        <StatusBar style="auto" />
      </View>
    </Provider>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Sample.tsx

```
import { View, Text, Button, TextInput } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { observer, inject } from "mobx-react";

function Sample(props: any){
    
    const { count, updateCount} = props.store
    console.log(count)
  return (
    <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <Text style={{fontSize:100}}>{count}</Text>
      <Button
        title='Press Me'
        onPress={updateCount}
      />
    </View>
  )
}

export default inject('store')(observer(Sample))
```

state.ts

```
import { makeObservable, observable, action, computed } from "mobx";

class State {
    constructor(){
        console.log('New Store')
        makeObservable(this, {
            count: observable,
            text: observable,
            currentCount: computed,
            updateCount: action
        })
    }
    count = 0
    text = ''

    get currentCount(): number {
        return this.count
    }

    updateCount(): void {
        this.count += 1
        console.log(this.count)
    }
    
}
export default State
```

Whenever I press the button, I am expecting the updateCount to update and re render my Sample.tsx component. However, that is not happening; and the 'console.log(this.count)' is coming back as undefined.

I am expecting my count being displayed to update automatically, but I am not seeing what I am missing. Would someone be able to provide insight into this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below code on state file and Sample file

```
export default stateStore = new State();
```

and

```
function Sample(props: any) {
  const { count } = props.store;
  function increase() {
    props.store.updateCount();
  }
  return (
    <>
      <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 100 }}>{count}</Text>
        <Button title="Press Me" onPress={increase} />
      </View>
    </>
  );
}
```

sample link :https://snack.expo.dev/@rudiahmad/mobx-sample

Comment: Thanks a lot for you're answer! It started working for me. Would you know why you can't access the updateCount from 'const { count, updateCount } = props.store;'? If I do this then pass in updateCount to onPress like '<Button title="Press Me" onPress={()=>updateCount()} />' it doesnt work?

Comment: nvm, it looks like its a known issue with mobx that they havent added in . https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/2629

Thanks again for the help!